# jquery plugin like Sass

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass

I want an easy way to create css files that contain different colors. [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) is actually doing the job quite well but There must be something I can do with javascript & jQuery ?
**basically I want to create the same file in different colors.**

```
**sample css file**
/* Variables */
$color1 = red;
$color2 = blue;
$color3 = white;
/* css code constants */

body {
  background-color : $color3;
  color : $color2;
}
h1 {
  color: $color1;
}
```

**Output**

```
body {
    background-color : white;
    color : blue;
}
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

**any idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS

http://lesscss.org/

works both server and client side.

Comment: I think he wants to programmatically change the colors.  If so he could just create a bigger css file with the CSS class corresponding to whatever color he wanted and do addClass/removeClass in jQuery.

Comment: Thank you. I think "LESS" was the answer to my question :)